# very bad performance by new WD 2TB GREEN(WD20EZRX) HDD

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs

i have a new WD GREEN WD20EZRX. I previously have 4 HDD : 3 X 1 TB (only one partition each)and 1 X 500 GB(2 partition one for WINDOWS and one for data).

i had no more power cable for the drive so i remove the dvd-drive SATA cable and power cable (as i no longer goona need it who used dvds nowdays :P)and put it into the NEW HDD (WD20EZRX). 
CPU:i7 920
RAM:3 GB DDR3
GPU:250 GTS

**Now the problem is the read/write speed is fluctuating a lot (50-1 MBps).** as i have windows 8 i can see the graph its full of up and down and average speed is very low 15-20 MB/s.

i searched and thought it was problem with the new ADVANCE FORMAT TECHNOLOGY but using the wd aligin software it showed it already aligned.

i remember when i first attached the HDD it asked me to format it normal NTFS or ADVANCE FORMAT TECHNOLOGY and i choose NTFS. idk it caused the problem .i cant find this option anymore anywhere.

any help will be usefull. if u need any kind of more information ask me.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to suggest that the limiting factor is the drive? The drive can't read any faster than the OS asks it to.

Answer (score 2):

Note that WD's green drives are optimized for power savings, not performance.  They use a variable-speed spindle (which they call "IntelliPower") that can slow down during low usage (and spin-down altogether when idle for a few minutes).  This means that when usage starts up again, you need to wait for it to come back up to full speed.  As far as I know, this is by design for the Green models.  But even under continuous use, spindle speeds for Green drives are typically slower than those for other models, so don't expect high performance.

If all this is a problem for you, I would recommend using some other model drive.  If you want to stick with a consumer-grade Western Digital, I would suggest either a Red or Black drive.  (Black is faster, but costs more.)

Answer (score 0):

The green drives are naturally slow, as that's why they're so cheap. As well, it would have asked to initialize it with mbr or gpt. It will format as ntfs if you're running Windows, automatically.